# Can you help me identify what sash lock key and bolt I need?

Tags: windows, lock

I live in a rented apartment on the ground floor of a council building in London.

As I live on the ground floor I'd love to have some extra security on the sash windows. The agency has no clue what type of locks are installed so I am hoping you can give me some help based solely on pictures. 
[image]
[image]
[image]

I've tried [these ones](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B07FZ8NSHX/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o08_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1) with no success. This [[Edina Sash Stop Lock]](https://www.inbrass.co.uk/acatalog/edina-sash-stop-lock.html) and [this](https://www.handlehardware.com/ekmps/shops/handlehardware/images/era-822-sash-stop-complete-with-key-electro-brass-1453-p.png) look promising; The shape of the stop on the lower sash makes me think it could be a [Yale WS1](https://www.tcfixings.co.uk/main/product/productinfo/6498/1/1?msclkid=2e415d0385b61b8f94a60393234dcb3b), but maybe you can identify them without me trying them out one by one.

Any leads are helpful!

Comment: Stuff the locks, a spring loaded centre punch takes out the layers of glass relatively quietly and they're in...  But why do you need a key? those locks look locked...

Comment: I know there's no absolute security but I'd like to know that there's an extra layer of protection. I'm not looking only for the key, but also the bolt that goes with it, I'll amend the original question so that it's clearer.

Comment: Based on the pictures I'm pretty sure the Yale WS1 is the lock you have. However, I'm not sure how that hels you. It's a keyless lock. If you want something with a bolt and key, purchase one for a double sash window and install it. You may need council approval.

Comment: I ordered keys for the WS1 and they don't fit, they were too large. The quest continues.